# Windows Vista volume limit

Tags: windows, windows-vista, audio

I like to watch videos on YouTube but sometimes they are not loud enough. Is there a way to bypass the volume limit so I can hear what the people are saying? I'm using a pair of ear buds because another person is watching TV in the same room, so I can't use special speakers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to boost Windows' sound volume to a higher limited value?](http://superuser.com/questions/58788/is-it-possible-to-boost-windows-sound-volume-to-a-higher-limited-value) also see [Increasing the sound volume in Windows Vista](http://superuser.com/questions/25503/increasing-the-sound-volume-in-windows-vista?rq=1)

Comment: I think the accepted answer of [Is it possible to boost Windows' sound volume to a higher limited value?](http://superuser.com/q/58788) is outdated. It couldn't find anything useful after following the link it provides.

Comment: @Dennis it's still the same question, it just needs updated answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without installing and third-part audio boosters (I know they exist, but I can't find any right now), here's what you can try:

1. Make sure actually all volume settings are at 100%.

   This includes the slider in the Youtube video plugin and both the volume of your audio device and application in the Volume Mixer (taskbar icon resembling a speaker).
2. If your motherboard has different 3.5 mm jacks for speakers and headphones, make sure to use the latter with your ear plugs.
3. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to open Windows Explorer and paste

   ```
   Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Sound
   ```

   in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   Select your device and click **Properties**.

   - In the **Custom** tab, make sure **Limited Output** is *not* checked.
   - In the **Enhancements** tab, try checking **Disable all sound effects**.
   - In the **Enhancements** tab, try checking **Loudness Equalization**.
   - In the **Enhancements** tab, try checking **Equalizer** and changing **Setting** to, e.g.,  **Powerful**.